# Can you make a burger from pepperoni?

Tags: beef, hamburgers, ground-beef

I was just thinking and I love pepperoni. Could you make a whole burger out of pepperoni? I wonder what this would taste like? It wouldn't be cheap of course.

It might be near to incorporate shredded pepperoni in a beef burger using ground beef, but I wonder if you can make a full burger out of pepperoni?

Comment: Would that just be a patty-shaped pepperoni instead of being in a link shape? It seems that would be a rather difficult-to-eat sandwich

Comment: You certainly *could* do it, but I'm not sure you should, or that it would taste as good as you hope it would.

Comment: Pepperoni slices mixed into the hamburger before cooking, then topped with a slice of mozzarella and a small dab of pizza/pasta sauce would be quite tasty. I've had philly cheesesteaks like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to answer the primary question, yes you could, but pepperoni is already cooked and processed and is hard (dried),it's easy to eat in small thin slices, but not in big chucks.

You could try grinding it down again and find a way to bind it in a patty (egg?breadcrumbs?) but the final texture might be weird,

pepperoni is also usually quite strong in taste and making a whole burger out of it would be overwhelming flavour (IMO).

As someone (SnakeDoc) wrote  in the comment, you could finely chop pepperoni and mix it with your burger meat.

pepperoni is more or less ground pork (or beef or mix of both) with spices and smoked.

As a substitute,

You could make a patty of ground pork and beef, add some pepperoni spices, including smoked paprika (or some liquid smoke) and use that as a burger meat.

Answer (score 0):

Pepperoni is usually higher in salt content. Just compare the salt content of typical burger patty meat with the salt content of a typical pepperoni meat:

- Burger patty (100g) - [74 mg](https://www.google.com/search?q=burger%20patty%20salt%20content)
- Pepperoni (100g) - [1,761 mg](https://www.google.com/search?q=pepperoni%20salt%20content)

As you can see, **pepperoni has about 20 times the amount of salt in burger patties**, so if you decided to make a burger patty out of pepperoni, the "patty" should be extra thin to balance out the salt.